# css equivalent of WPF data template binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a collection of objects in JS with a name and two boolean fields, which looks like the following.

```
{
    "Name": "testname",
    "ReadAccess": true,
    "WriteAccess": false
}
```

I keep these in a collection on my angular controller as so

```
$scope.permissions = permissionArray;
```

Which I'm currently binding to a select box as so

```
<select size="20" style="width: 585px" ng-disabled="disableControls" ng-model="ComputePermissionsService.selectedPermission" ng-options="permissions.Name for permissions in ComputePermissionsService.Permissions"></select>
```

Which gives me a tall select window with the name of each permission.

I want to mimic the Select box functionality and display my collection of objects as a scrollable list, however I want to do something I used to do in WPF and redefine the DataTemplate for the data row. So for each object that binds as an Option to the Select, I want to display the Name as a label, then two check boxes representing the Boolean values on my object. I want these to be clickable so I can toggle them and have this update the underlying JS object so if I then click save, all I have to do is send the data to the server to update.

This used to be easy in WPF with custom DataTemplates but I'm not sure if this is possible in CSS/JS/HTML. Can someone suggest a clean way to do this?

Comment: Yes, create a directive.

Comment: Or go for 3rd party implementations https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect